# Position absolute div width doesn't match parent

Tags: html, css

I changed child div's `position` to `absolute` so that it can fill up rest of the page. But now it's width doesn't match with parent body. Code is not straightforward as I am using Angular 2.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <hp-root></hp-root>
</body>
```

**app.html**

```
<div>
  <md-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <img src="../assets/logo_3x.png" class="top-logo"/>
    <a class="top-link">Home</a>
    <a class="top-link">Candidates</a>
    <a class="top-link">Jobs</a>
    <a class="top-link">Blog</a>
    <a class="top-link">Login</a>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
<hp-candidate-list></hp-candidate-list>
```

**candidate-list.html**

```
<div class="page">
  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  <div class="items">
      <md-nav-list *ngFor="let candidate of candidates">
        <md-list-item>
          <img src="../../../assets/reminder-active@3x.png" class="reminder">
          <span class="name">{{candidate.name}}</span>
          <span>{{candidate.experiences[0].title}} at {{candidate.experiences[0].companyName}}</span>
          <span>{{candidate.skills[0].name}}, {{candidate.skills[1].name}}, {{candidate.skills[2].name}}</span>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-nav-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

div.items {
  max-width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

After adding the `position: absolute` `.page` div fills up rest of the page but looks like this:

[image]

Before width was fine but it's height wasn't filling up the page.

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: 100%` to the abspos div? Also, add `position: relative` to `body`.

Comment: As @Michael_B said parent div have to have `position:relative` property.

Comment: @Michael_B Doesn't work. It fixes the width but I loose the child div of page and height doesn't cover rest of the page.

Comment: It's important (and part of SO guidelines) that you provide all relevant code in your question. This allows us to reproduce the problem and help you more effectively. Otherwise, we waste time guessing and going down wrong paths.

Comment: @Michael_B Updated with rest of the code. Hope it make more sense now.

Comment: Does your header have a fixed height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you set an element to `position: absolute`, that removes it from the normal content flow, the size of the the element will be the size of the content inside, unless to declare the `width` and `height`, or set  relevant `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` values.

Example of making an position absolute element to take full width of the closest container with `position` set other than `static`, or if it sits directly under `body` tag.

```
.page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Example of making div main to fill entire height available by using flexbox.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background: gold;
}
.main {
  background: silver;
  flex: 1;
}
.footer {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```